# When to use on("selector") and when on("selector", "selector")

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery `on()` version 1.7. I bind my events usually like this:

```
$(".foo").on("click", function() {
    console.log("foo clicked");
})
```

Now after seeing someone elses code, I seen you also can bind like this, specifying a secondary parameter for a specific element (Not sure why it was written like this):

```
$(document).on("click", ".bar", function() {
    console.log("bar clicked");
})
```

As seen in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWUyn/1/), they both do the same thing.

I always bind directly to the element as in the first code sample and never have any issues.

When would I need to use the other way of binding and what is the benefit of one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second code example is equivalent to the deprecated now [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event. So you will use it situations when you want to subscribe to events of DOM elements that don't yet exist in the DOM in the moment of subscription (think for example elements added to the DOM after an AJAX call).

Your first example is perfectly equivalent to `$(".foo").click(function() { ... });`.

Comment: So, does that mean one way is redundant as we could always use the second way of binding I guess? What is the benefit using one over the other and when would you know which one you need?

Comment: No, absolutely no. Those two constructs do different things and should be used based on your requirements. If you are not dynamically adding elements to your DOM to which you need to subscribe to some events then you could use the first construct. If on other hand you need to work with dynamic DOM elements then the second is more appropriate as the first won't do anything if the selector doesn't return any element.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. The second sample, I assume is for binding an event to an element which doesn't exist at the time the document is ready but may be injected later. So far I have manualy bound my events when elements were injected so I never had the need but now I might make use of it. Seems to save some manual late binding. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Jason, yes, it's exactly that.

Comment: Accepting this answer cause it was posted first but the other answers are also very informative and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on("click", ".bar", function() {
    console.log("bar clicked");
});
```

it's instead of the now deprecated `.live()` method
it's for delegating your event handler directily to element/s (dynamically generated 'on the go')

---

If you use `$('.button').on('click',function(){` and let's say you generate dynamically a button - the click on that element will do nothing.
If you use `$('#navigation').on('click','.button',function(){` the click handler is being attached (delegated) to any present and future `.button` element making it clickable.

Where `$(document)` (it's slower) can be your parent element: `$('#your_parent')` (faster)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I always manually late-bound, never realised you can do that with `on()`. Good to know :)

Comment: @Jason You're welcome! here you can play to see the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/zZwtP/

Comment: Sweet, I updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/zZwtP/1/) and I now see how, when you bind before document ready for example but then on document ready append the element you bound to, only the syntaxt of my second sample works. Very nice. Thank you for the fiddle :)

Answer (score 2):

Always use the nearest parent element. jQuery watches the events bubbling up and attaches them as soon as it finds one, this is called Event Delegation. When you use `document` which is also default, jQuery has to wait until that instead of closest parent element of the clicked element.

Your first example works for elements that are supposed to be present there when you bind an event to them while later approach works for both present and newly/dynamic created elements

Comment: +1 for "event delegation".  Always use the nearest parent element that is NOT dynamically created.  Event delegation may also be useful for repeating elements with the same handler attached - for example, `$("table").on("click", "td", function ...)` may be better than registering an event handler on each individual td - although I don't understand well enough to explain it.

Comment: It's good to know it is much easier than I thought to bind to dynamic elements. Thank you.

Comment: @wrschneider99: Absolutly right, I will not get into the habbit of using `$(document)` but as stated in the post, use the nearest existing element. Thanks for highlighting this again.